# Do mipmaps react to scale transformations?

Tags: opengl

When using mimaps, does OpenGL select a mipmap based on the final transformed size of the surface, or based only on the size of the surface in local space?

In other words, if I scale a polygon larger, this could/should affect which mipmap gets selected, when all other aspects of the polygon remain unchanged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's based on the final transformed size. Or more accurately, it's based on the screen-space coordinates for the fragment being processed. So yes, if your transform makes your polygon very small, it will select a smaller image for texturing, whereas if the transform makes your poly big, it will select a more detailed mip level.

It even properly handles the case where your polygon covers a range from near the viewer to far away. (Like if you rotate a polygon around the x or y axis, so one end is very close to the viewer, and the other end is very far away.) Nearby pixels will use a more detailed mip level, and far away ones in the same polygon will use the less detailed level.

Comment: Specifically mipmaping levels are chosen by the screen space slope of the texture coordinate gradient. Regular mipmapping chooses the maximum of the two partial derivatives, while *anisotropic* filtering chooses two separate mipmapping levels based on either partial derivatives and adjust the mixing kernel accordingly.